# Mono .NET on linux - String comparisons failing

Tags: .net, mono

I'm diving into Mono for the first time and getting rather some odd (aka impossible) behaviour.

I'm compiling in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows, then copying over the binaries to a virtual machine running CentOS 6.5 with the latest stable version of Mono runtime.

When I run the binary within the Mono runtime, a string comparing method fails to behave as expected.  It works fine the first time, but then later in the execution phase it behaves differently, and `String.Equals(...)` returns FALSE even though the strings are identical.

```
public static class DBUtils
    {

        public static string ProviderConnectionStringFromEFConnectionString(string efConnectionStringName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("DBUTILS:");
            Console.WriteLine("We are looking for '{0}'", efConnectionStringName);
            string efConnString = getConnectionString(efConnectionStringName);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(efConnString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR - EFConnString is blank or null");
                return "";
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Got EF connection string which is '{0}'", efConnString);

            // <snip>
        }

        static string getConnectionString(string connStringName)
        {
            System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            var csSection = config.ConnectionStrings;

            Console.WriteLine("Searching {0} connection strings for {1}...", csSection.ConnectionStrings.Count, connStringName);

            for (int i = 0; i < csSection.ConnectionStrings.Count; i++)
            {
                var conn = csSection.ConnectionStrings[i];

                Console.WriteLine(" compare {0}<=>{1}", conn.Name, connStringName);

                if ( conn.Name == connStringName)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FOUND " + conn.Name);
                    return conn.ConnectionString;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("NOT FOUND");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

...console output is as follows.  The above method is run twice both times, with different results:

```
DBUTILS:
We are looking for 'transit_UK_intranet'
Searching 4 connection strings for transit_UK_intranet...
 compare LocalSqlServer<=>transit_UK_intranet
 compare LocalSqliteServer<=>transit_UK_intranet
 compare transit_UK_intranet<=>transit_UK_intranet
FOUND transit_UK_intranet
Got EF connection string which is 'metadata=res://*/Transit.TransitModel.csdl|res://*/Transit.TransitModel.ssdl|res://*/Transit.TransitModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=transportdata.fatattitude.intranet;user id=root;password=mys***y;persist security info=True;database=transit_uk"'
```

Then, later:

```
DBUTILS:
'e are looking for 'transit_UK_intranet
...rching 4 connection strings for transit_UK_intranet
 compare LocalSqlServer<=>transit_UK_intranet
 compare LocalSqliteServer<=>transit_UK_intranet
 compare transit_UK_intranet<=>transit_UK_intranet
 compare transit_UK_live<=>transit_UK_intranet
NOT FOUND
ERROR - EFConnString is blank or null
```

The string passed to the method is a Public Static string held in another class, which is referenced as part of a constructor in another class which then calls this Static helper method.

Does anyone have any thoughts?   I have noticed the odd console corruption in the second output, above.  (`'e are...` and `...rching`).

**

### Update 2:

**

As requested by Jon Skeet, here's the console output with solely Length/Hashcode comparisons.

```
DBUTILS:
We are looking for 'transit_UK_intranet'

connStringName as unicode chars:0074,0072,0061,006E,0073,0069,0074,005F,0055,004B,005F,0069,006E,0074,0072,0061,006E,0065,0074

Searching 4 connection strings for transit_UK_intranet...
 Compare (Length:14,Hash:-1122305114)<=>(Length:19,Hash:1351687580)
 Compare (Length:17,Hash:1337257306)<=>(Length:19,Hash:1351687580)
 Compare (Length:19,Hash:1351687580)<=>(Length:19,Hash:1351687580)
FOUND transit_UK_intranet
```

Second method call:

```
DBUTILS:
'e are looking for 'transit_UK_intranet

 connStringName as unicode chars:0074,0072,0061,006E,0073,0069,0074,005F,0055,004B,005F,0069,006E,0074,0072,0061,006E,0065,0074,000D

...rching 4 connection strings for transit_UK_intranet
 Compare (Length:14,Hash:-1122305114)<=>(Length:20,Hash:-1047357967)
 Compare (Length:17,Hash:1337257306)<=>(Length:20,Hash:-1047357967)
 Compare (Length:19,Hash:1351687580)<=>(Length:20,Hash:-1047357967)
 Compare (Length:15,Hash:-529357175)<=>(Length:20,Hash:-1047357967)
```

Calling code:

```
 Console.WriteLine(" Compare (Length:{0},Hash:{1})<=>(Length:{2},Hash:{3})", 
 conn.Name.Length, conn.Name.GetHashCode(),
 connStringName.Length, connStringName.GetHashCode() );
```

Comment: I suspect some of your strings may have unprintable characters in. Try printing the hash code and length as well as the strings themselves...

Comment: I've done as you suggested @JonSkeet and pasted the results into the question - it's really very odd, the console output now corrupts even more. The hashes/lengths of the Strings being passed are wildly inaccurate by the looks of things.

Comment: I *strongly* suspect the strings have unprintable characters in them  - and that's almost certainly what's messing up the console output too. Next up, I suggest that you log the unicode characters (e.g. using `string.Join(",", conn.Name.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X4")))`. Consider not printing out `conn.Name` itself, to avoid the console output from getting corrupted.

Comment: Ah, you are right (output pasted into question).  It's actually the single String being passed to the method that contains an unprintable character the second time the method is called - it has 000D appended to it. Oddly, though, there is no code that re-assigns this String object between the two calls, and it works fine on Windows .NET.  So, I guess my question is: what could be causing a Static String in memory to become altered on Mono, but not on the normal .NET runtime?  Some Unicode incompatibility/platform-specific String storage implementation?

Comment: Differing string terminators or line ending characters?

Comment: I suspect the value really *is* being changed somewhere in your code, but you haven't found out where yet. I've never seen string objects change their data under Mono yet... I think it's much more likely that it's a simple bug *somewhere* in your code - but in the code that *calls* this method rather than the method itself.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're absolutely right of course.  The first time the method is called is from a debugging line that I added, using a hard-coded `String`. The second time, the `String` comes from a file, which is split via `Environment.NewLine` which, of course, is a platform-dependent constant. Mystery solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0x000D char is \r, so it looks like some of the code may not treat the end of line sequence correctly. Hard to say without seeing all the code if this is in mono code or in your own or in some support library code.

Specifically, on Linux and other unix systems, line termination is signalled by a single char, \n, while on windows it's \r\n. So code that uses windows text lines, but unix terminators may remove just the \n at the end of a line, so you are left with the \r char, which you can't see in the console but it messes the output and the strings compare differently.

Comment: That's exactly right.  I was splitting a text file with `Environment.NewLine` which is platform-dependent.  I've switched to `File.ReadLines()` which should, I hope, produce the desired result.